# Hide "next" link if json requests returns the next link as "false"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, if-statement

```
$("#wrap .project").append($("<a id='previous-project' href='"+ path + "#project/" + data.prev + "'>previous</a><a id='next-project' href='"+ path + "#project/" + data.next + "'>next</a>"));
```

Messy, I know. The `path` is the main path of course and `data.prev` and `data.next` are links to the next project.
Naturally projects get to an end and then when I hover or click on the link it gives me path/false.

I tried this:

```
        if(data.next == false){$('#wrap .project #prev-project').hide()};
        if(data.prev == false){$('#wrap .project #next-project').hide()};
```

But it doesn't hide anything. I am alerting the `data.next` and `data.prev` and it gives me false. I tried 'false'  as well in the if, nothing, the links are still showing.

What's the problem?

Comment: Are `data.prev` and `data.next` boolean value? If they are returned as text then you will have to compare with "false" string.

Comment: Can you please show the value of `data`. Also you're hiding `#prev-project`, but the HTML you append is `#previous-project`. Finally, check the console for any errors

Comment: You should probably post the JSON as well, but you could always try........,,,,,,,,,,.......,,,,,,,,,,,,.....,,,,,,,... : `if (! Boolean(data.prev.trim() ) {$('#next-project').hide(); }`

Comment: could you put an alert in the true part to see if it is the if going wrong or the hide.

Comment: if you are using ids you don't need so complex select statements, since the id is supposed to be unique anyway...

Comment: data is just an array of images and the current, prvious and next id-s. If I there is no next id in the database it gives me "false". And the prev-project was a typo, the mark-up is all fine. adeneo, your code didn't sadly work. data.next itself is an int, an id of a node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about :

```
var prev = data.prev ? '<a id="previous-project" href="'+ path + '#project/" ' + data.prev + '">previous</a> ' : '<span class="nolink">previous</span> ';
var next = data.next ? '<a id="next-project" href="'+ path + '#project/" ' + data.next + '">next</a>' : '<span class="nolink">next</span>';
$("#wrap .project").append(prev + next);
```

Create a `.nolink {...}` style in your stylesheet to style null prev/next text, eg. `.nolink { color:#e0e0e0; }`.

You don't need the ids unless they are used elsewhere.